# Specify whether the series $\sum_{n=n_0}^{+ \infty } a_n \cdot b_n$ must be convergent in cases a) or b)

Tags: real-analysis

Specify whether the series $\sum_{n=n_0}^{+ \infty } a_n \cdot b_n$ must be convergent when:
a) $\sum a_n$ convergent, $\sum b_n$ convergent
b)$\sum a_n$ convergent absolutely, $\sum b_n$ convergent.
I need to check my reasoning and I need help to guide them further:
If $\sum b_n$ convergent, then in particular a sequence of partial sum $\sum b_n$ is convergent, so the second condition of Dirichlet's test is met. That is why we should take care of $a_n$. The first condition of Dirichlet's test is $a_n$ monotonic and $a_n$ convergent to $0$. So I think in the case of a) the series $\sum_{n=n_0}^{+ \infty } a_n \cdot b_n$ not always is convergent and b) must be convergement, but there are only my thoughts and I do not know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case a counter-example is given by

$$a_n=b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt n}$$

For the second  and since $\sum b_n$ is convergent so for sufficiently large $n$ we get
$$\vert b_n\vert \le 1$$
hence
$$\vert a_n b_n\vert\le \vert a_n\vert$$
hence the series $\sum a_n b_n$ is absolutely convergent.